# Puppeteer PDF export table headers

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to export page with html table to PDF using puppeteer.

```
  await page.pdf({
    format: 'Letter',
    printBackground: true
  });
```

For some reason it makes table headers sticky, like this:

[image]

I tried 3 different PDF viewes and it's always the same. (ones without continus scrolling just put it on top of every page, but still overriding other text)

Comment: Have you tried printing to PDF from a normal browser, any issues there?

Comment: Yes, it looks normal(no text overlap) from a normal browser. Any ideas?